# Mysql Left Join не делает выборку из второй таблицы

Tags: mysql, join

Запрос имеет вид:

```
SELECT 
    p.*, 
    pp.* 
FROM 
    parts p 
    LEFT JOIN products pp ON p.sn LIKE '%pp.sn%' 
WHERE 
    p.id = 16449
```

В обоих таблицах есть поле sn varchar 255 с одинаковым значением вида `1121312 (3453)`.
В итоге в выборке из products NULL - т.е. выборка не случилась.

Comment: *значением вида 1121312 (3453)* А Вы ищете в нём подстроку `'pp.sn'` - с ожидаемо отрицательным результатом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> LEFT JOIN products pp ON p.sn LIKE '%pp.sn%'
> ```

SQL так не работает, вы не можете ожидать, что строка волшебным образом распарсится в ссылку на значение из столбца в какой-либо таблице.

Если уж на то пошло, то пишите вот так - явно переводя ссылку в значение и склеивая строку:

```
LEFT JOIN products pp ON p.sn LIKE '%' + pp.sn + '%'
```